# How can I merge specific parts of my XML file

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have an XML file which I have exported from Excel to give me what i need. It was a one time operation to get hold of the data in XML and it has come across exactly how i need apart from one issue.

The XML file contains thousands of entries for Tasks, each task lists the various supplies required to do that task. Each task should only appear once although it can obviously have a number of supplies listed within it.

The problem is that where it's come across from Excel, if a task has, say, 3 supplies required, it has generated the task 3 times each one containing only one supply.

I Therefore need to merge the supplies with a common task into one single task. This will be a one time operation and the data will be managed in XML from here on.

example XML below :

```
<tasks>
        <task>
            <taskCode>123456</taskCode>
            <taskName>Mow lawn</taskName>
            <supplies>
                <tool>
                    <id>Edge trimmer</id>
                </tool>
            </supplies>
        </task>
        <task>
            <taskCode>123456</taskCode>
            <taskName>Mow lawn</taskName>
            <supplies>
                <tool>
                    <id>Lawn mover</id>
                </tool>
            </supplies>
        </task>
        <task>
            <taskCode>45678</taskCode>
            <taskName>Paint wall</taskName>
            <supplies>
                <tool>
                    <id>Paint brush</id>
                </tool>
            </supplies>
        </task>
</tasks>
```

In this example i need the first two tasks merged so that we end up with:

```
<tasks>
        <task>
            <taskCode>123456</taskCode>
            <taskName>Mow lawn</taskName>
            <supplies>
                <tool>
                    <id>Edge trimmer</id>
                    <id>Lawn mover</id>
                </tool>
            </supplies>
        </task>
        <task>
            <taskCode>45678</taskCode>
            <taskName>Paint wall</taskName>
            <supplies>
                <tool>
                    <id>Paint brush</id>
                </tool>
            </supplies>
        </task>
</tasks>
```

Comment: This is a grouping issue. Can you say if you are using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 as the solution differs for each? In XSLT 1.0 you can use a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). In XSLT 2.0, you can use the dedicated construct [xsl:for-each-group](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html).

Comment: Hi, I'm using .net which as far as I know only supports 1.0 although I may well be wrong. Thanks.

Comment: If you using xsltcompiledtransform then that is indeed 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq to XML allows you to make a GROUP BY query.

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse("YOUR XML DATA");

var tasks = xdoc.Descendants("task")
                .GroupBy
                (
                    t => t.Element("taskCode").Value, // group on taskCode value
                    t => t,
                    (k, g) => new XElement // Make a new "task" element
                    (
                        "task",
                             new XElement("taskCode", k), // with the taskCode
                             g.Select(x => x.Element("taskName")).FirstOrDefault(), // taskName, just pick the first one
                             new XElement("supplies", g.Select(x => x.Element("supplies").Element("tool")).ToList()) // merge the "tools"
                    )
                );

xdoc.Element("tasks").ReplaceNodes(tasks); // then inject updated nodes back in the xml
```

Results :

```
<tasks>
    <task>
        <taskCode>123456</taskCode>
        <taskName>Mow lawn</taskName>
        <supplies>
            <tool>
                <id>Edge trimmer</id>
            </tool>
            <tool>
                <id>Lawn mover</id>
            </tool>
        </supplies>
    </task>
    <task>
        <taskCode>45678</taskCode>
        <taskName>Paint wall</taskName>
        <supplies>
            <tool>
                <id>Paint brush</id>
            </tool>
        </supplies>
    </task>
</tasks>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll try this when I get the chance and mark accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create classes for the original mapping, create classes for the new mapping, then deserialise into the original classes, create a mapping to the new classes, and serialise it out to the new format.

Comment: Alternately, you could go with XSLT but I suspect that would take longer than writing C# to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the XSLT 1.0 solution, you would use a technique called Muenchian Grouping. As you want to group the `task` elements by `taskCode` you first define a key like so

```
<xsl:key name="tasks" match="task" use="taskCode" />
```

And then, to get the `task` elements with the first occurrence of each possible taskCode you would do this

```
<xsl:template match="tasks">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="task[generate-id() = generate-id(key('tasks', taskCode)[1])]" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You then just use the key to add in all the extra `id` elements under `tool`. Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="tasks" match="task" use="taskCode" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tasks">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="task[generate-id() = generate-id(key('tasks', taskCode)[1])]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tool">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('tasks', ../../taskCode)/supplies/tool/id" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of the identity template which handles copying the elements you don't need to change.